# Crystal Reports Formula editing - Summing up a field by multiple conditions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report with 2 group names - Customers and Products
I'm trying to sum up a field "Total" From Orders for each product by customer
but i only want to sum the lines with specific fields values

for example:
If {OrderProducts.X} = Y And {OrderProducts.V} <> W Then
SUM({OrderProducts.Quantity},{Products.ProductID})

when using SUM with condition field i get the entire sum without any regards to the the above field values.

i'd appreciate some help with this

(I'm using Crystal Reports 2011)

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach:

- create a formula field:

  //{@product}
  //generate a product for selected products; NULL otherwise
  If {OrderProducts.X} = Y And {OrderProducts.V} <> W Then 
    {OrderProducts.Quantity}*{Products.ProductID}
- Place formula on canvas (in Details section)
- Select field, then select Insert | Summary ...
- Remove formula field, if desired (it doesn't need to be on the canvas for the summary to work correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Running Total Field" (View >> Field Explorer)

**Field to summarize** - product.quantity

**Evaluate** - Select "Use a forumla" and give your condition there

e.g.

```
if (product.x=Y and product.v<>W) then 
product.quantity
else
0
```

**Reset** - select your customer field

Hope this helps

Comment: Mr. @Radiodef - what exactly did you edit in my answer above? I don't see any **improvement** as such! You shouldn't edit just because you _can_ edit

Comment: I edited in proper code formatting. I have the [privilege to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). You shouldn't complain about having your presentation improved in a small way.

Comment: Oh I see.. there was a space that you removed! Had you cared to mention that while you edited (if I'm not wrong - there is an option to do so) - we would've avoided this conversation altogether.